# Image from jpgraph keeps loading forever

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm using jpgraph.php and I have the following code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/jpgraph/jpgraph_pie.php');
$data = array(239,175,62,52,31,441);
$graph = new PieGraph(500,500,'auto');
$graph->SetColor('#008CBE');

[...more code here...]

$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->Stroke();
```

After I open the php script from a browser it outputs the image correctly, but the page keeps loading.
After ~ 1 minute the browser returns 'Failed to load resource' and the image changes from a valid PNG image to a broken one.

Here's a link: http://www.standartnews.com/index2.php

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong. On my local machine everything works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: On my local machine it works fine, but on the server it keeps the browser loading. There is output, but if you stay on the same page for ~ 1 minute the server will return 'Failed to load resource' and the image will break.

Comment: Have you tried this with different browsers?

Comment: Works fine for me as well. But I see that your script/server responds with an HTTP header `Connection: keep-alive` – but it does not send a `Content-Length` header as well. That might get some browser into waiting for more data.